# How to debug a remote linux binary?

Tags: linux, gdb, remote-debugging

Here is the situation:

I've got a linux binary that is crashing. No log files, trace files, etc. I need to be able to attach a debugger to it (I have the source locally) and track down the error.

Whats the easiest, best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remote debugging is rather straightforward: on the target platform, launch the application with GDBserver, while specifying the host and port for listening to an incoming TCP connection:

```
  gdbserver HOST:PORT PROG [ARGS ...]
```

On the development workstation, launch the cross-target GDB:

```
  powerpc-7450-linux-gnu-gdb PROG
```

Be sure to specify the non-stripped executable. At the GDB console, type:

```
  target remote HOST:PORT
  break main
  continue
```

[Remote cross-target debugging with GDB and GDBserver](http://www.linux.com/feature/121735)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gdb supports remote debugging.

I've never used it but http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_17.html looks like a start.

Basically you run the program under gdbserver on the target machine, and gdb connects (over TCP or serial) to the gdbserver.